# Calculating time complexity which life of algorithm depend to the user input

Tags: time

Can we calculate the time complexity of an algorithm which its life depends to the user input?
(i.e the while loop continue until user type 10).

sorry if my question is unreasonable. I'm new in time complexity

Answer (score 0):

No. You can not find the time complexity in case of such programs. If you are waiting for user input to terminate the program, the time requirement could be any thing between zero and infinity. Here the time taken by the program to terminate on each execution is also different. Also you should not confuse your program with probabilistic algorithms. Probabilistic algorithms are an entirely different class of problems.